# in hook_views_pre_render, how to get the current display of the ViewExecutable

Tags: views

I have this code:

```
function my_module_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if (isset($view) && $view->storage->id() == 'myview') {
    // Do something.
  }
}
```

This runs my code for all displays of my view, hoever, if I have page_1 and page_2 displays, and I only want to pre-render page_2, I can't figure it out:

I am looking for something like this:

```
function my_module_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if (isset($view) && $view->storage->id() == 'myview' && $view->getDisplayId() == 'page_2') {
    // This does not work
    // Do something.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just `$view->current_display === 'page_2'` that you're looking for.
Also, in my experience, you don't need "storage" to get the view id; you can just use `$view->id()`